Does Flood Control's damage reduction apply to Armor?
Poseidon's boon Flood Control says

After you enter a Location, Prime 30 Magick to reduce any damage you take.

Does that damage reduction apply to damage against Armor you've obtained, either bought from Charon or received from Arachne's outfits?


Damage reduction from damage-reducing boons (such as Poseidon's Flood Control) is calculated before affecting the player's total life, which means both their normal life amount and the extra amount given by the armor. So yes, it also applies to all the sources of armor points you can gain in the game.
